# Sard's Theorem with different Measures

Tags: manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

From what I can tell Sard's theorem is formulated in terms of the Lebesgue measure.  Is there a form of Sard's theorem for more general measures (in particular, those which are not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure?).

Comment: Your question created the tag (topological-manifolds). But there is already a tag (manifolds). Was this an oversight or were you trying to make a point? [ Also, isn't Sard's Theorem a statement involving differentiable manifolds? I don't actually know; just want Wiki tells me :D ]

Comment: Yeah, Sard's theorem (as taught in any "geometry of manifolds", "differential manifolds", "smooth manifold theory" course) is a statement involving a function between differentiable manifolds.  And the only result I'm aware of involves the Lebesgue measure.  I'm simply wondering if there are more general settings where we can say something with a measure that is not absolutely continuous wrt the L. measure.  I would guess we'd have to make our topologies more abstract and loose the smooth structure.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'm changing the tag.